# I can not insert data using ajax in Laravel, I got 500 internal server error always and i do not know why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel and ajax, There is a contact form at home page and I wanna user to able to submit this form without refreshing the page, but always got this internal server error.

I am using laravel 5.8 and jquery, I've tried solutions like using another jquery version or including the csrf or not and all is the same.

insert function at HomeController

```
public function contactForm(Request $request) {

        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'message' => 'required|string'
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        if($request->fails()) {
            $failed_output = [];
            foreach ($request->getMessages()->messages() as $message) {
                $failed_output[] = $message;
            }
        }else {
            $data = $request->except('_token');
            DB::table('user_messages')->insert($data);

            $success_output = "<div class='alert alert-success'>We got your message, thank you.</div>";

        }
        $output = [
                'success' => $success_output,
                'error' => $failed_output,
            ];

        return response()->json([
            'success' => $success_output
        ], 200);
        // echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

my route

```
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@contactForm')->name('home');
```

html Form

```
<form id="contactForm" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/">

                            <span id="form_output"></span>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="email" placeholder="Your email..." value="@auth {{ auth()->user()->email }} @endauth" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                                <p class="home-email-input js-error">Email is not valid</p>

                                @if($errors->has('email'))
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                                    </div>
                                @endif

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Tell us why you like this website..." name="message" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                                <p class="home-message-input js-error">You message must be between 10 - 500 characters.</p>

                                @if($errors->has('message'))
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        {{ $errors->first('message') }}
                                    </div>
                                @endif

                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" value="Send">

                        </form>
```

javascript code (ajax call)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $("#contactForm").submit(function(evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();

        let email = $("#contactForm div #email").val();
        let msg = $("#contactForm div #message").val();

        if(email.length < 10) {
            $("#contactForm div p.home-email-input").css("display", "block");
            return false;
        }
        if(msg.length < 10 || msg.length > 500) {
            $("#contactForm div p.home-message-input").css("display", "block");
            return false;
        }

        // Insert By Ajax

        let form_data = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data: form_data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.error.length > 0) {
                    let errors = "";
                    for(let i = 0; i < data.error.length; i++) {
                        errors += "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+data.error[i]+"</div>";
                    }
                    $("#form_output").html($errors);
                }else {

                    $("#form_output").html(data.success);
                    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
                }
            },

        });

    });
```

I wanna the result to be a little success message above the input but I got this error :

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: A 500 error means somewhere in our logs are details of the error.

Answer (score 0):

`Illuminate\Http\Request` does not have a `fails` method, that would be a method to call on a `Validator` instance.

When you call `$this->validate(...)` in your Controller that will throw an Exception if the validation fails, there is nothing for you to check after that in your Controller. If execution has continued after `$this->validate(...)` that means that the validation passed.

Comment: Thank you I spent a lot of time trying to solve it thanks